# Nemo Randomly Makes Itself Default File Manager and Creating Desktop Shortcuts

Tags: 14.04, nautilus, restart, nemo

I've installed Nemo but haven't made it default and I have nothing on my desktop. But sometimes when I boot up I see Computer, Home and Trash icons on my desktop and suddenly Nemo is the default file manager as when I click any of my shortcuts or the new icons on my desktop Nemo appears. When I restart it all returns to normal.

My question is...well... WTF?! I was testing out Nemo and intending to replace Nautilus with something else but this stuff is really weird, can someone tell me what's going on? Should I uninstall Nemo? I'm really new to Ubuntu or Linux in general but I didn't find where those icons would be disabled when I look at my Desktop on Nemo via opening by the shortcut on my Desktop, it shows nothing is there.

When I look for Desktop Icons in Unity Tweak Tool appereantly nothing is there and they don't go away when I tinker with the settings.

But after I restart 1 or 2 times the problem disappers and everything goes back to normal.

So please, somebody help me make some sense out of this. Also could someone tell me how to uninstall a software thoroughly in Ubuntu? It always leaves a lot of junk behind from my experience.

Screen Shot 1, The Problem: [image]

Screen Shot 2, Two Restarts Later every thing is back to normal: [image]

Answer (score 0):

To completely remove nemo:

```
sudo apt-get remove --purge nemo
```

Comment: Thanks, do you think removing Nemo is necessary/useful regarding my condition?

Comment: Well as you still have nautilus, you'll be fine. It's not gonna hurt anything. Remove it when the icons have gone to be safe.

Answer (score 0):

Copy and paste the below command in terminal exactly to not show shortcuts on Desktop.

```
gsettings set org.nemo.desktop home-icon-visible false;
gsettings set org.nemo.desktop trash-icon-visible false;
gsettings set org.nemo.desktop computer-icon-visible false;
gsettings set org.nemo.desktop volumes-visible false;
```